# Turning an animated object into a mesh without the animation?

Tags: animation, mesh

I have used the cloth engine, shape keys and animation to create a bunched up curtain. I now want to make that final bunched curtain into a mesh that I can use in other projects without the animation. Is this possible? And if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the *Cloth* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did try that, but it gives an error that says "Modifier cannot be applied to a mesh with shape keys". When I use the other option of "Apply as Shape Key" it returns the plane to its original shape, taking out all of the bunching/folds.

Comment: remove all the shape keys except the one you want to apply, and remove this one at last?

Comment: That worked. Thank you.